# ¿Por qué ocurre este problema con NgForm de Angular?

Tags: nodejs, angular, express

Tengo este componente:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from '../../services/data.service';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-datas',
  templateUrl: './datas.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./datas.component.css'],
  providers: [DataService]

})
export class DatasComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private dataService: DataService) { }

  ngOnInit() {}

  addData(form: NgForm) {
    this.dataService.postData(form.value)
      .subscribe(res => {
        this.resetForm(form);

      })
  }

  resetForm(form?: NgForm) {
    if(form){
      form.reset();
      this.dataService.selectedData = new Data();
    }
  }

}
```

Y veo que obtengo este error:

> ERROR in src/app/components/datas/datas.component.ts(29,43): error TS2304: 
>   Cannot find name 'Data'.

Me doy cuenta que también hay un error en el archivo service, el cual es el siguiente:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import { Data } from '../models/data';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataService {

  selectedData: Data;
  datas: Data[];
  readonly url = 'http://localhost:3000/api/datas';

  constructor(private http:HttpClient) {
    this.selectedData = new Data()
  }

  getDatas() {
    return this.http.get(this.url);
  }



  postData(data: Data) {
    return this.http.post(this.url, data); // En vez de "Data", escribes "data"
}

deleteData(_id:string) {
    return this.http.delete(this.url + `/${_id}`); // En vez de "data._id", escribes "_id"
}


  putData(data: Data) {
    return this.http.put(this.url + `/${data._id}`, data);

  }


}
```

y por si las dudas aca les dejo mi archivo de models:

```
import { FormsModule }   from '@angular/forms';

  imports: {
    FormsModule
  }

export class Data {

  constructor(_id="", code="", direction="", tech=0){
    this._id = _id;
    this.code = code;
    this.direction = direction;
    this.tech = tech;
  }

  _id: string;
  code: string;
  direction: string;
  comment: string;
  tech: number;
}
```

Que estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: En la función `deleteData()` usas la variable `data`, dentro de `http.delete()` y esa variable no está definida allí.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes esto:

```
postData(data: Data) {
    return this.http.post(this.url, Data);
}

deleteData(_id:string) { 
    return this.http.delete(this.url + `/${data._id}`);
}
```

En `postData()`, dentro de `http.post()`, escribiste data con mayúscula, y en `http.delete()` no puedes poner `data._id`, ya que `data` no existe dentro de `deleteData()`.

Tiene que ser así:

```
postData(data: Data) {
    return this.http.post(this.url, data); // En vez de "Data", escribes "data"
}

deleteData(_id:string) { 
    return this.http.delete(this.url + `/${_id}`); // En vez de "data._id", escribes "_id"
}
```

Recuerda que también tienes que importar el modelo Data en `datas.component.ts`:

```
import { Data } from '../models/data' // La ruta puede ser distinta.
```

Comment: pues ahora tengo este error: ERROR in src/app/components/datas/datas.component.ts(29,43): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Data'.

Comment: Son errores de tipografía, ya actualicé la respuesta.

Comment: hermano, me da este error: ERROR in src/app/components/datas/datas.component.ts(29,43): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Data'. acabo de actualizar la pregunta, para ver si me puedes ayudar,

Comment: Tienes que importar Data en datas.component.ts, revisa la nueva respuesta.